# Changing the size of icons Magento rwd-theme

Tags: rwd-theme

I am customising the rwd theme but have some problems.

I need to style the icons for the rwd-theme

I would like to:-
1.increase the icon size
2. display the label underneath rather than to the side
3. make the header fixed, i have managed this by changing position: fixed in .page-header but this causes contents of this div to lose position, managed to fix most apart from the basket icon that insists on placing itself in the top right of the page.

I am using the sass files to edit the style sheets
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This answer only addresses the first point of your question:

You can find the PSD file that was used to create the sprites in the RWD theme by looking for the "Working With Sprites" heading on this page: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide#customize-theme-images

If you download the RWD_icon_sprite.psd, you can easily edit the icon sizes inside of the Smart Object that is inside that PSD.